# Add padding for animation

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I use this Material-UI with React to generate a button:

```
<Grid container direction="column" justifyContent="center" alignItems="center">
                <Grid item>
                    <Box m={3}  >
                        <div id="activate-description">
                            <h4 className='activate-text'>test</h4>
                            <Link to='activate'>
                                <button className='activate'>Activate</button>
                            </Link>
                        </div>
                    </Box>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
```

There is a default button animation which is increasing the button size with 1px. Is there some way to add for example additional div layer to compensate the small button resize when the mouse is over?

***EDIT*** rendered html:

```
<div class="MuiBox-root MuiBox-root-1495">
   <div id="activate-description">
      <h4 class="activate-text">You’re in test mode</h4>
      <a href="/activate"><button class="activate">Activate production account</button></a>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's usually best to work these problems with HTML and CSS, not React markup, just as you'd do in your browser's dev tools. Please post the rendered HTML and any related CSS in a functioning snippet.

Comment: I updated code.

Comment: You gave us one of the three things I asked for. :/